# Archivo de Excel generado en php y mysql no abre?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo que crea el archivo en excel pero no abre y el lo abri con mi editor de codigo.

```
<?php

    require 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, precio, existencia FROM productos";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $fila = 2;

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("C.T")->setDescription("Reporte de Productos");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Productos");

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'NOMBRE');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'PRECIO');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'EXISTENCIA');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'TOTAL');

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['id']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['nombre']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['precio']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['existencia']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, '=C'.$fila.'*D'.$fila);

        $fila++;

    }

    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Productos.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Y me muestra esto:

> 0950 4b03 0414 0002 0008 0082 4aa4 4c47
>   9244 b258 0100 00f0 0400 0013 0000 005b
>   436f 6e74 656e 745f 5479 7065 735d 2e78
>   6d6c ad94 4d4e c330 1085 f79c 22f2 1625
>   6e59 2084 9a76 4161 0995 2807 30f6 a4b1
>   ead8 9667 fa77 7b26 690b 0889 40d5 6e62
>   45f6 7bdf f879 ecd1 64db b86c 0d09 6df0
>   a518 1603 9181 d7c1 58bf 28c5 dbfc 29bf
>   1319 92f2 46b9 e0a1 143b 4031 195f 8de6
>   bb08 98b1 d863 296a a278 2f25 ea1a 1a85
>   4588 e079 a60a a951 c4bf 6921 a3d2 4bb5
>   0079 3318 dc4a 1d3c 81a7 9c5a 0f31 1ebd
>   303f 5903 d94c 257a 560d 63e4 d649 6237
>   d87f 8705 fb89 ec61 2f6c d9a5 5031 3aab
>   1571 e172 edcd 0f6a 1eaa ca6a 3041 af1a
>   9614 9dcd 75eb 227f 0522 ed1c e0d9 288c
>   0994 c11a 801a 57ec 4d8f e429 546a e528
>   7bdc b2fb 3ef3 040e 4fe3 1dc2 2c58 d9ad
>   c1da c63e 42ff 867e d7ad cf0c 82f5 d3a4
>   36dc 4a3d a16f 425a be87 b0bc 74ec ed58

Comment: En teoría ya genera el excel correctamente. ¿Has probado si puedes abrir cualquier otro archivo de excel, en esa versión con extención .xlsx ?

Comment: Es ofice 2010 el que teno en mi pc